# Retriving json value with the help of path in c++

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I am currently working on a project to retrieve value from a Json through the path acquired from a json schema as I want to get the values of only those keys that are present in the json schema from the Json.

### Paths from where I need to retrieve the values:

```
/array/0
/boolean
/null
/object/a
/object/c
/object/e
/number
/deep_nested_array/0/object_array1/0/key4
/deep_nested_array/0/object_array1/1/key5
/deep_nested_array/0/object_array1/2/key6
/object_array/0/key1
/object_array/1/key2
/object_array/2/key3
/string
```

### Json from where I want to retrieve the value from:

```
{
 "array": [
   1,
   2,
   3
],
"boolean": true,
"null": null,
"number": 123,
"object": {
  "a": "b",
  "c": "d",
  "e": "f"
 },
 "string": "Hello World", 
 "object_array": [
    {"key1": "value1" },
    {"key2": "value2" },
    {"key3": "value3" }
    ],
  "deep_nested_array": [
       {"object_array1": [
          {"key4": "value4" },
          {"key5": "value5" },
          {"key6": "value6" }
       ]}
        ,
       {"object_array2": [
          {"key7": "value7" },
          {"key8": "value8" },
          {"key9": "value9" }
       ]}
     ]
 }
```

### I only want to return

```
[
   1,
   2,
   3
]
true
null
b
d
f
123
Hello World
value1
value2
value3
value4
value5
value6
```

Order will be dependent on the path passed , doesnt matter.

### My code

```
  static string findValue(const Value &item, string path) {
    StringBuffer s1;
    Writer<StringBuffer> w1(s1);
    item.Accept(w1);
    cout << "recursing:" << s1.GetString() << endl;
    cout << "Original Path:" << path << endl;
    string delimiter = "/";
    size_t pos = 1;
    string token, paths;

    token = path.substr(0, path.find(delimiter));
    cout << "token:" << token << endl;
    const Value &element = item[token.c_str()];
    StringBuffer s;
    Writer<StringBuffer> w(s);
    element.Accept(w);
    cout << "items matching the token:" << s.GetString() << endl;
    while ((pos = path.find(delimiter)) <= path.find(delimiter)) {
        paths = path.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        cout << "paths:" << paths << endl;


        if (paths.length() > 1) {
            if (element.IsObject()) {


                findValue(element, paths);
            } else if (element.IsArray()) {

                for (SizeType i = 0; i < element.Size(); i++) {
                    if (element[i].IsArray() || element[i].IsObject()) {
                        findValue(element[i], paths);
                    } else {
                        cout << "Array returning:" << s.GetString() << endl;
                        return s.GetString();
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            cout << "item returningg:" << s.GetString() << endl;
            return s.GetString();

        }
    }

}
```

### My output

```
recursing:{"array": 
[1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object": 
{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"string":"Hello World","object_array": 
[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}, 
{"key3":"value3"}],"deep_nested_array":[{"object_array1": 
[{"key4":"value1"},{"key5":"value2"},{"key6":"value3"}]}, 
{"object_array2":[{"key7":"value4"},{"key8":"value5"}, 
{"key9":"value6"}]}]}

Original Path:array/
token:array
items matching the token:[1,2,3]
paths:
item returningg:[1,2,3]

recursing:{"array": 
[1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object": 
{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"string":"Hello World","object_array": 
[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}, 
{"key3":"value3"}],"deep_nested_array":[{"object_array1": 
[{"key4":"value1"},{"key5":"value2"},{"key6":"value3"}]}, 
{"object_array2":[{"key7":"value4"},{"key8":"value5"}, 
{"key9":"value6"}]}]}

Original Path:boolean/
token:boolean
items matching the token:true
paths:
item returningg:true

recursing:{"array": 
[1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object": 
{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"string":"Hello World","object_array": 
[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}, 
{"key3":"value3"}],"deep_nested_array":[{"object_array1": 
[{"key4":"value1"},{"key5":"value2"},{"key6":"value3"}]}, 
{"object_array2":[{"key7":"value4"},{"key8":"value5"}, 
{"key9":"value6"}]}]}

Original Path:null/
token:null
items matching the token:null
paths:
item returningg:null

 recursing:{"array": 
[1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object": 
{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"string":"Hello World","object_array": 
[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}, 
{"key3":"value3"}],"deep_nested_array":[{"object_array1": 
[{"key4":"value1"},{"key5":"value2"},{"key6":"value3"}]}, 
{"object_array2":[{"key7":"value4"},{"key8":"value5"}, 
{"key9":"value6"}]}]}

Original Path:object/a/
token:object
items matching the token:{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}
paths:a/
recursing:{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}

Original Path:a/
token:a
items matching the token:"b"
paths:
item returningg:"b"
paths:
item returningg:{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"} //Dont need this to be 
                                            returned
recursing:{"array": 
[1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object": 
{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"string":"Hello World","object_array": 
[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}, 
{"key3":"value3"}],"deep_nested_array":[{"object_array1": 
[{"key4":"value1"},{"key5":"value2"},{"key6":"value3"}]}, 
{"object_array2":[{"key7":"value4"},{"key8":"value5"}, 
{"key9":"value6"}]}]}

Original Path:object/c/
token:object
items matching the token:{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}
paths:c/
recursing:{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}
Original Path:c/
token:c
items matching the token:"d"
paths:
item returningg:"d"
paths:
item returningg:{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}

recursing:{"array": 
[1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object": 
{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"string":"Hello World","object_array": 
[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}, 
{"key3":"value3"}],"deep_nested_array":[{"object_array1": 
[{"key4":"value1"},{"key5":"value2"},{"key6":"value3"}]}, 
{"object_array2":[{"key7":"value4"},{"key8":"value5"}, 
{"key9":"value6"}]}]}

Original Path:object/e/
token:object
items matching the token:{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}
paths:e/
recursing:{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}
Original Path:e/
token:e
items matching the token:"f"
paths:
item returningg:"f"
paths:
item returningg:{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}

recursing:{"array": 
[1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object": 
{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"string":"Hello World","object_array": 
[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}, 
{"key3":"value3"}],"deep_nested_array":[{"object_array1": 
[{"key4":"value1"},{"key5":"value2"},{"key6":"value3"}]}, 
{"object_array2":[{"key7":"value4"},{"key8":"value5"}, 
{"key9":"value6"}]}]}

 Original Path:number/
 token:number
 items matching the token:123
 paths:
 item returningg:123
 recursing:{"array": 
 [1,2,3],"boolean":true,"null":null,"number":123,"object": 
 {"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"},"string":"Hello World","object_array": 
 [{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}, 
 {"key3":"value3"}],"deep_nested_array":[{"object_array1": 
 [{"key4":"value1"},{"key5":"value2"},{"key6":"value3"}]}, 
 {"object_array2":[{"key7":"value4"},{"key8":"value5"}, 
 {"key9":"value6"}]}]}

 Original Path:deep_nested_array/object_array1/key4/
 token:deep_nested_array
 items matching the token:[{"object_array1":[{"key4":"value1"}, 
 {"key5":"value2"},{"key6":"value3"}]},{"object_array2":[ 
 {"key7":"value4"},{"key8":"value5"},{"key9":"value6"}]}]

 paths:object_array1/key4/

 recursing:{"object_array1":[{"key4":"value1"},{"key5":"value2"}, 
 {"key6":"value3"}]}
 Original Path:object_array1/key4/
 token:object_array1
 items matching the token:[{"key4":"value1"},{"key5":"value2"}, 
 {"key6":"value3"}]
 paths:key4/
 recursing:{"key4":"value1"}
 Original Path:key4/
 token:key4
 items matching the token:"value1"
 paths:
 item returningg:"value1"

 recursing:{"key5":"value2"}
 Original Path:key4/
 token:key4

 validationjson: 
 /home/mavericks/CLionProjects/validationjson/ 
 include/rapidjson/document.h 
:1137: rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>& 
 rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::operator[](const 
 rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, SourceAllocator>&) [with 
 SourceAllocator 
 = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>; Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; 
 Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>]: Assertion `false' 
 failed.

This error is because the for loop for the IsArray is continuing with
```

the token as key 4 and path as key4/ rather than ending.
Help in solving this will be appreciated.

Comment: At what point exactly does your program not behave as expected? Can you provide a [mcve]? BTW: If this is getting too big for you to manage, consider writing unit tests. They will make sure that you don't break stuff in one place while fixing another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to the question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "include/rapidjson/document.h"
#include "include/rapidjson/pointer.h"
#include "include/rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "strings.h"
#include "cstring"


using namespace std;
using namespace rapidjson;

class test {

public:
static bool parseJson(const string &json1, const string &json2, const 
string &temp) {
    Document d;
    d.Parse(json1.c_str());
    Document d1;
    d1.Parse(json2.c_str());
    Document d2;
    d2.Parse(temp.c_str());

    Pointer root;
    bool match = getPath(d,d1, d, d1, d2, root);

    return match;
}

static bool getPath(const Value &item1, const Value &item2, const Value &value, const Value &value1, const Value &v, const Pointer &parent) {
    bool match = true;


    if (v.IsObject())
        for (Value::ConstMemberIterator itr = v.MemberBegin(); itr != v.MemberEnd(); ++itr) {

            if(value.HasMember(itr->name)&&value1.HasMember(itr->name)) {
                match = getPath(item1,item2, value[itr->name.GetString()], value1[itr->name.GetString()], itr->value, parent.Append(itr->name.GetString()));

            }
            else{
                match=false;
                break;
            }

            if (match == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    else if (v.IsArray()) {
        auto len = v.Size();
        auto len1 = value.Size();

        cout<<"length of item1:"<<len1<<endl;
        auto len2=value1.Size();
        cout<<"length of item 2:"<<len2<<endl;
        SizeType i = 0;


        for (SizeType i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if(len>len1||len1!=len2){
                match=false;
                break;
            }
           else  if (len == len1) {
                match = getPath(item1,item2, value[i], value1[i], v[i], parent.Append(i));

                if (match == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                for (SizeType j = 0; j <= len; j++) {
                    match = getPath(item1,item2, value[j], value1[j], v[i], parent.Append(j));
                    if (match == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    } else {

        StringBuffer sb;
        parent.Stringify(sb);

        string path = getPaths(sb.GetString());

        cout<<"paths:"<<path<<endl;

        string val = findValue(item1, path);

        cout<<"value1:"<<val<<endl;
        string val1 = findValue(item2, path);

        cout<<"value2:"<<val1<<endl;

        if (val != val1||val=="Dont have the key in the json"||val1=="Dont have the key in the json") {

            match = false;
            return match;

        }
    }

    return match;
}

static string getPaths(string path) {
    path = path.erase(0, 1);
    path = path + "/";
    return path;
}

static string findValue(const Value &item, string path) {

    StringBuffer s1;
    Writer<StringBuffer> w1(s1);
    item.Accept(w1);

    cout << "value recursed:" << s1.GetString() << endl;

    string delimiter = "/";
    size_t pos = 1;
    string keys, paths, result;

    keys = path.substr(0, path.find(delimiter));

    if(path.length()>1) {
        if (item.HasMember(keys.c_str())) {
            const Value &element = item[keys.c_str()];
            StringBuffer s;
            Writer<StringBuffer> w(s);
            element.Accept(w);


            paths = path.erase(0, keys.length() + 1);

            if (paths.length() > 1) {
                if (element.IsObject()) {
                    StringBuffer s1;
                    Writer<StringBuffer> w1(s1);
                    element.Accept(w1);

                    cout << "value sent:" << s1.GetString() << endl;
                    cout << "Paths:" << paths << endl;
                    result = findValue(element, paths);
                } else if (element.IsArray()) {
                    string token = path.substr(0, path.find(delimiter));

                    int key = stoi(token);

                    paths = paths.erase(0, token.length() + 1);
                    if (element[key].IsArray() || element[key].IsObject()) {

                        result = findValue(element[key], paths);


                    } else {

                        StringBuffer s1;
                        Writer<StringBuffer> w1(s1);
                        element.Accept(w1);

                        // cout << "value sent:" << s1.GetString() << endl;
                        return s1.GetString();
                    }
                }

            } else {

                // cout << "Value sent outside:" << s.GetString() << endl;
                return s.GetString();
            }
        } else {
            result = "Dont have the key in the json";
            return result;
        }
    }else{
        return s1.GetString();
    }
    return result;
}
};

int main() {
const char *item1 = "{  \"array\": [    { \"x\": [1,2,2]},    2,    3  
]}";
const char *item2 = "{  \"array\": [    { \"x\": [1,2,2]},   2,    3  
]}";
const char *temp = "{  \"array\": [    null  ]}";

bool match = test::parseJson(item1, item2, temp);
cout << match;
}
```